# How do I get rid of this star shaped mark on a sphere?

Tags: modeling

[image: Inside the red circle]

I've seen these weird marks before but I usually get rid of them by making an invert ring by pressing I. But in this case, this doesn't make any rings. Perhaps because it's curved? It worked on a flat circle. What do I do then?